# Restful web service using jetty and jersey returns 404

Tags: rest, embedded-jetty, jersey-2.0

I'm having trouble with my restful web service using embedded jetty and jersey. I'm starting the jetty server from inside of an ecplise application and I try to communicate with the server using a jersey client.

I built the restful web service based on this tutorial: http://jlunaquiroga.blogspot.se/2014/01/restful-web-services-with-jetty-and.html

I had some problems migrating the tutorial from Jersey 1.x to 2.x but finally I got the web server up and running. Now, the problem is that it does not respond to requests from client (or browser). Does anyone know why?

Here is my code:

**Provider package:**

```
package org.eclipse.eatop.jetty.helloworld.rest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType; 


@Path("/xmlServices")
public class XMLProjectService {
  @GET     
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)     
  public String getProject() 
  {         
      return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> hello world </hello>" ;     
  }
}
```

Jetty embedded server:

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    Server server = new Server(8080);         
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    server.setHandler(context);
    ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer());
    sh.setInitOrder(1);
    sh.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "org.eclipse.eatop.jetty.helloworld.rest");
    context.addServlet(sh, "/*");

    try {
        server.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Unable to start jetty web server");
   e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return null;
}
```

**Client:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI()).path("xmlServices");
        System.out.println(target.request("text/xml").get());
    }
    private static URI getBaseURI() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/").build();
    }
}
```

**The result I get :**

```
 InboundJaxrsResponse{ClientResponse{method=GET, uri="http://localhost:8080/xmlServices", status=404, reason=Not Found}}
```

Comment: I should mention I'm using Jetty 9.2.0.RCO and JavaSE-1.7 and Jersey 2.12.

Comment: If it's any help:
+= org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@14efd00 - STARTED += org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer-1b05ad2@3c64e64b==org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer,1,true - STARTED 
+-jersey.config.server.provider.packages=org.eclipse.eatop.jetty.helloworld.rest 
+- [/*]=>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer-1b05ad2 += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet-980200@76a611b5==org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet,-1,false - STARTED +- [/]=>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Default404Servlet-980200

Answer (score 0):

Try this change ...

From:

```
ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer());
```

To:

```
ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
```

That's the way that your linked to article uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I too struggled on this part for two days and found that the rootcause lies in lazyinitialization of ServletContextHandler. Start your contexthandler once you start your jetty server. It will work fine.